# Tense selection to describe previously-developed software

Tags: tenses, software

I am in the process of writing documentation for a software project. I would like to understand what would be the best tense to use for the description of the code/tools that had been (?) developed by the time I started writing the document.

For example, consider the following sentence:

> This document describes the programming conventions used in the library development, the library directory structure and the supplementary tools that **were/have been/had been** developed to support and manage the library development. The main part of the library **is/were/have been/had been** written in C++.

What would be the best tense to use in each case?

Comment: This is a matter of style, not of "rules" (so we can't offer answers to this question, unfortunately). My personal preference for documentation is it should be practical and helpful in a pragmatic sense, and as a consequence of that,   should focus on the software as it exists *today*: when I'm trying to get a job done, the history of the technology is irrelevant. Therefore, I would phrase your first bolded statement: "*the directory structure and tools **that** support and manage ..*" (who cares that the tools "were developed"? they *exist*). Similarly, I'd suggest "*the main part **is**..*".

Comment: "Used in the library development" seems awkward to me. Something like "used in the development of the library", "used in library development", or "used in the library" would be smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coding was done in the past; you're doing the documentation now.  Therefore, I would not use the present tense.

... tools that were developed etc.

The main part of the library was written in C++.

Comment: I will accept your answer to close the question. However, it does not seem that there is a right or wrong answer here (see comments after my question).

Comment: Agreed, you could use the present tense if that feels more comfortable.  I usually did when I was writing my own programs.  But when I was maintaining old code, and wanted to write some documentation for future use, I used the past tense.  That was when I was a COBOL programmer, ha ha!